# How to Upload XML File to TomCat?

Tags: c#, tomcat

I have a TomCat server running a couple of webapps.

I would like to upload an XML file onto my TomCat server so I can access and download the file with a program I am developing in C#.

I've done a lot of searching and I have no solid leads, so how do I upload a file to a Tomcat server so it can be accessed?

```
For example, I want my program to be able to use this: 
get file from(http://tomcat-ip:port/example/data.xml)
```

Thank you.

---

**Figured out the solution: Place the file in webapps/root and you will be able to access the file from hostname:port/filename**

---

Comment: Figured out the solution: Place the file in webapps/root and you will be able to access the file from hostname:port/filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your tomact server in XAMPP you can put your `xml` file in `C:\xampp\htdocs`
code:

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://localhost/data.xml);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
   Sysetm.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

If you have html table too you can make array:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputLine);
            Elements tables = doc.select("table");
            for (Element table : tables) {
                Elements trs = table.select("tr");
                String[][] trtd = new String[trs.size()][];
                for (int i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {
                    Elements tds = trs.get(i).select("td");
                    trtd[i] = new String[tds.size()];
                    for (int j = 0; j < tds.size(); j++) {
                        trtd[i][j] = tds.get(j).text(); 
                    }
                }
                // trtd now contains the desired array for this table
                    System.out.println(trtd[column][row]);
            }
```

Comment: If you are making array you need Jsoup library

Comment: If you have tomcat server in eclipse then make a project with data.xml inside

Comment: Sorry...I'm a bit confused.  If I wanted to simply upload a file onto my tomcat server (from the server computer itself), do I need code?

My thought was that I would simply need to put the file in the proper location and maybe change some configurations around?

Thanks

Comment: Dont worry you only need code if you are going to read data using java

Comment: What program are you using to run tomcat server ?

Comment: I'm running apache-tomcat 7 straight from the bin/startup.bat

My issue right now is uploading the file on the server so I can access it through the network

Comment: You can upload your xml file in `C:\apache-tomcat\webapps\`

Comment: I placed my XML file in c:\apache-tomcat\webapps

but when i try to connect to localhost:8080/data.xml

I'm unable to connect to it.

Thanks

Comment: Got it working.  I added the data.xml file into the ROOT folder in webapps.

I now see my XML file.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you restared server after placing xml file ?